# Is something wrong with my proof? $span(A \cup span(B))$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to prove the following identity for subsets of a vector space $V$:

$A, B \subset V$

$ \langle A \cup \,\langle B\rangle\,\rangle=\langle A \cup B\rangle $

---

My idea so far:

I know that for subsets in a vectorspace we have

$B \subset \langle B\rangle$.

Therefore it is obvious that

$ \langle A \cup B \rangle\subset \langle A \cup \langle B \rangle \rangle$

But how can I prove the opposite inclusion:

$\langle A \cup \langle B\rangle\rangle\subset \langle A \cup B\rangle$?

Comment: Hint: Take an arbitrary vector from $span(A\cup span(B))$ and show that it is in $span(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that
$$A \subset span (A \cup B)$$
and
$$span B \subset span (A \cup B)$$
hence the union $A \cup spanB$ is a subset of $span (A \cup B)$. Now, take spans, and you get
$$span (A \cup B) \subset span ( span (A \cup B)) = span (A \cup B)$$